# Error when trying to include plotly plot in rmarkdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I created a nice pie chart. Nothing too fancy.

```
Source <- plot_ly(Question1_2016, labels = Question1_2016$Source, values = Question1_2016$TotalExpense, type = 'pie')
```

in the area of my RMarkdown file, I can not seem to get the correct coding to get Source embedded in it.

My plot chunk looks like this:

````
```{r source, echo=FALSE}
Source 
```
````

and when I go to knit it together I get this error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object "Source" no found Calls: <Anonymous>...handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval _. eval Execution Halted
```

Any idea?

Edited to add:

```
dput(Question1_2016[1:5, ])
structure(list(FY = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), Source = c("All Other Sources", 
"Business", "Federal", "Institutional Support", "Institutional Support-Cost Sharing"
), TotalExpense = c(1819424.18, 2850796.2, 47625255.58, 33363659.29, 
6922360.06), Percent = c(1.5, 2.3, 39.2, 27.5, 5.7), Labels = c("All Other Sources 1.5 %", 
"Business 2.3 %", "Federal 39.2 %", "Institutional Support 27.5 %", 
"Institutional Support-Cost Sharing 5.7 %")), .Names = c("FY", 
"Source", "TotalExpense", "Percent", "Labels"), row.names = c(11L, 
22L, 33L, 44L, 55L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edited to Add my RMarkdown:

---

title: "UMD"
author: "Laura Walker"
date: "February 16, 2017"

### output: html_document

`{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)`

### R Markdown

## Loading the Libraries

`library(readxl)
library(reshape)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)`

### Loading the Data Sets

`ExpendData <- read_excel("C:/Users/user/Desktop/ExpendData.xlsx", 
+     na = "empty")
SponsorData <- read_excel("C:/Users/user/Desktop/SponsorData.xlsx")
ProjectData <- read_excel("C:/Users/user/Desktop/ProjectData.xlsx")`

## Defining UltimateSponsor

In the cases where there is a Prime Sponsor, I've developed code to create an Ultimate Sponsor. When there is a Prime, the Ultimate Sponsor will take the identity of the Prime. When there is just a sponsor, the Ultimate Sponsor will take that identity. 

`ExpendData$UltimateSponsorID <- ifelse(ExpendData$Prime=="N", ExpendData$PrimeSponsorID, ExpendData$SponsorID)`

## Merging expend data with other tables

Merging expend data with sponsor data based on Ultimate Sponsor

`ExpendData <-merge(x=ExpendData, y=SponsorData, by.x="UltimateSponsorID", by.y="SponsorID")`

Merging expend data with project data based on project#

`ExpendData <-merge(x=ExpendData, y=ProjectData, by.x="ProjectNumber", by.y="PROJECT")`

### Question 1

Question 1 asks "How much of your total expenditures for research and development R&D came from the following sources"

`Question1 <-aggregate(TotalExpense~FY+Source, CurrentFY, sum)
Question1 <-Question1[order(Question1$FY),c(1:3)]`

Extracting data for only FY 2016

`Question1_2016 = subset(Question1, FY == "2016")`

Constructing an FY16 Source of Funding Pie Chart
```
Question1_2016$Percent <- round(Question1_2016$TotalExpense/sum(Question1_2016$TotalExpense)*100, digits = 1)
Question1_2016$Labels <- paste(Question1_2016$Source, Question1_2016$Percent)
Question1_2016$Labels <- paste(Question1_2016$Labels, "%",sep = " ")

Source <- plot_ly(Question1_2016, labels = Question1_2016$Source, values = Question1_2016$TotalExpense, type = 'pie')

```

You can also embed plots, for example:

`{r plot, echo=FALSE}
plot(Source)`

Comment: Where are you creating the pie chart? Why don't you just create the chart inside of the markdown chunk?

Comment: Thank you @GarAust89 I created it in another chunk and it doesn't appear either

Comment: Constructing an FY16 Source of Funding Pie Chart
```
Question1_2016$Percent <- round(Question1_2016$TotalExpense/sum(Question1_2016$TotalExpense)*100, digits = 1)
Question1_2016$Labels <- paste(Question1_2016$Source, Question1_2016$Percent)
Question1_2016$Labels <- paste(Question1_2016$Labels, "%",sep = " ")

Source <- plot_ly(Question1_2016, labels = Question1_2016$Source, values = Question1_2016$TotalExpense, type = 'pie')

```

Comment: Please make your question reproducible so that we can run your code on our systems.

Comment: When you run the code to create `Source` interactively, do you get an error?

Comment: @eipi10 How does one create the item interactively?

Comment: In your console paste in the following code and press Enter: `Source <- plot_ly(Question1_2016, labels = Question1_2016$Source, values = Question1_2016$TotalExpense, type = 'pie')` If your code works, that should create an object called `Source` containing the pie chart. Then if you type `Source` in the console, the pie chart should be displayed in a viewer window. Or you can just paste `plot_ly(Question1_2016, labels = Question1_2016$Source, values = Question1_2016$TotalExpense, type = 'pie')` into the console and see if that produces a plot or returns an error.

Comment: @eipi10 of course! Yes. I do get a pie chart in my plot area. I just don't know how to embed them in my Rmarkdown file.

Comment: Well, to figure out why your code is not working, we need a reproducible example: That is, a complete rmarkdown document (complete but minimal--the smallest document needed to illustrate your problem) that includes a small data sample (use `dput` for this) to try out your code on. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more on providing a reproducible example.

Comment: can i share it with you via google dirve?

Comment: Much better to run `dput(Question1_2016[1:5, ])` and paste the output of that into your question (not into a comment).

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you! i've done it above

Comment: Thanks for providing a full `rmarkdown` document. However, you need to remove all the data loading and processing code and instead provide the actual data for `Question1_2016` in a code chunk. Otherwise we can't run it. Follow the example in my answer for how to do this. Then `knit` the document and make sure it still gives the same error before posting it here.

Comment: Also, the last line of your rmarkdown document has a few errors: (1) period after fig.width=8 instead of a comma. (2) `source` instead of `Source` and (3) `plot(Source)`, which will give an error with a plot_ly object, instead of just `Source`.

Comment: @eipi10 thank you for your patience. I think I extracted all the extraneous stuff. I'm still getting errors though :-(

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but just an illustration of what we need to be able to answer your question. Below is a minimal reproducible example. It also runs without error, which is why we need more information to figure out why your document isn't compiling.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

dat = data.frame(x=seq(10,100,length=5), group=LETTERS[1:5])
```

```{r]}
library(plotly)
Source = plot_ly(dat, labels=~group, values=~x, type="pie")
```

```{r source, echo=FALSE}
Source 
```
````

Based on the data you provided, I still don't get an error in the document below. The error you posted suggests that `Source` isn't actually being created when you run the `Source <- plot_ly(...` code. Can you paste into your question a complete `rmarkdown` document that, when compiled, exhibits the error you posted?

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(plotly)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
Question1_2016 = structure(list(FY = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), Source = c("All Other Sources", 
"Business", "Federal", "Institutional Support", "Institutional Support-Cost Sharing"
), TotalExpense = c(1819424.18, 2850796.2, 47625255.58, 33363659.29, 
6922360.06), Percent = c(1.5, 2.3, 39.2, 27.5, 5.7), Labels = c("All Other Sources 1.5 %", 
"Business 2.3 %", "Federal 39.2 %", "Institutional Support 27.5 %", 
"Institutional Support-Cost Sharing 5.7 %")), .Names = c("FY", 
"Source", "TotalExpense", "Percent", "Labels"), row.names = c(11L, 
22L, 33L, 44L, 55L), class = "data.frame")
```

```{r}
Source <- plot_ly(Question1_2016, labels = Question1_2016$Source, values = Question1_2016$TotalExpense, type = 'pie')
```

```{r}
Source
```
````